# In cache-Control header field why does it named as "directives"?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control, http-1.1

I wanted to know why standard HTTP/1.1 header fields define **Cache-Control** as **directives** ?
and other header fields not marked as same.

I went though the all standard HTTP/1.1 header fields [https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html] definition it only apply with Cache-Control general-header field except **Pragma** general-header field where I also does not have idea.

Answer (score 1):

Well for a start RFC 2616 has been superseded by RFC [7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234)

At a guess I would say they are “directives” as they MUST be obeyed, as opposed to other headers which do not define any specific behaviour.

The original HTTP/1.1 RFC 2616 [has this to say](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.1.3), over which I have highlighted some relevant phrases:

> **13.1.3 Cache-control Mechanisms**
>
> The basic cache mechanisms in HTTP/1.1 (server-specified expiration
> times and validators) are ***implicit directives*** to caches. In some
> cases, a server or client might need to provide ***explicit directives***
> to the HTTP caches. We use the Cache-Control header for this purpose.
>
> The Cache-Control header allows a client or server to transmit a
> ***variety of directives*** in either requests or responses. These
> directives typically override the default caching algorithms.